# How to reset password in Django by sending recovery codes instead of sending link

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

Can anybody explain how to use the **recovery codes to reset the password** using recovery codes instead of recovery links like of  Facebook ,Gmail etc.

I'd like to reduce the pages user have to open. Here're what I want:

1. instead the reset link, send to user the key only

Comment: You need to generate the key, which is normally some hash of some user id, a timestamp and something else, then just send that, then when they enter it, you reverse engineer the data, make sure it matches and hasn't timed out (hence the timestamp) and either error or proceed. Alternatively, just a numeric code but you're storing this specific code against the user, and still with a timeout, but make sure it's not subject to a brute force attack in this case!